# Can I take over a dbus name to proxy calls through my service

Tags: linux, dbus

I would like to inject my own service between two services using dbus to communicate.
I would like to control what goes to the other service without doing source modifications to the two daemons currently communicating.

Is this even possible?

[edit] A comment made me realize that I was maybe not clear enough. Both services are on the same host.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusRemote/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to modify what bus connection at least one of the services connects to, you could use a proxy for the bus and intercept and interact with the traffic between the two services.

E.g.: https://github.com/Pelagicore/dbus-proxy